# How to set an elements initial state to be hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use an extention that allows me to edit the css of Youtube.
I need the navigation menu on the left of youtube home page to be hidden when the webpage loads and appear when the menu button is clicked.

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqSHM.png)

Is there any way I can do this?

The extention can use Javascript too.

HTML code when the bar is open:

```
<tp-yt-app-drawer id="guide" align="start" role="navigation" class="style-scope ytd-app" style="transition-duration: 0ms; touch-action: pan-y;" position="left" swipe-open="" opened="" persistent="">
```

HTML code when the bar is closed:

```
<tp-yt-app-drawer id="guide" align="start" role="navigation" class="style-scope ytd-app" style="transition-duration: 0ms; touch-action: pan-y;" position="left" swipe-open="" persistent="">
```

HTML code of the button

```
<yt-icon-button id="guide-button" toggleable="true" class="style-scope ytd-masthead"><!--css-build:shady--><button id="button" class="style-scope yt-icon-button" aria-label="Guide" aria-pressed="true">
```

Comment: You can add `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`

Comment: Well put `display: block` or something on the regular state, I'll write an answer for you if you edit your question to follow question guidelines for SO

Comment: Doesnt work cause then it wont appear even if I click the button

Comment: Okay I will take look at the guidlines

Comment: We also need the code of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps?

```js
document.getElementById("guide-button").onclick = function() {  
  myFunction() 
}; 
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("guide");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<tp-yt-app-drawer id="guide" align="start" role="navigation" class="style-scope ytd-app" style="transition-duration: 0ms; touch-action: pan-y; display:none;" position="left" swipe-open="" opened="" persistent="">

<yt-icon-button id="guide-button" toggleable="true" class="style-scope ytd-masthead"><!--css-build:shady--><button id="button" class="style-scope yt-icon-button" aria-label="Guide" aria-pressed="true">
```

Comment: Is there a way i can add onclick="myFucntion()" to yt-icon-button ?
I cant think of any

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that, have edited the code above.